# How do you publish an Access 2013 DB to a local website?

Tags: localhost, ms-access-2013

My computer is Windows 7 Pro.  I have IIS 7 installed and running.  I've created a new site under port 81 called "access"

I have Access 2013.  I'm just testing using the basic Asset Tracking template.  I give my app a name "test" and my web location is http://localhost:81.

When I try to create the app, I get the message:
An error occurred while attempting to connect to the server http://locahost:81.  Check spelling of the server name.
HTTP Status Code:  404

I can browse to the local URL.  I have a default.htm file in the root folder of the website and I can clearly see what's in my htm file.  I know the web server is working.

What could be going on with my access app?  I couldn't find anything on google related to a local website - just stuff about publishing to SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

Just an IIS is not enough. You will need Sharepoint running locally if you want to save it locally. You can either save the Access App on OneDrive / OneDrive Business or a Sharepoint / Sharepoint Online Teamsite.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj249372.aspx) you can read more about the requirements.